# [imp]ose an [imp]losion

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There're only 54 questions tagged [imp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imp), but the tag has no usage guidance, which makes it attract questions from different categories:

- [`imp` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) from Python standard library.
- Integrative Modeling Platform
- Implementation
- Import
- Electric Imp, Inc.
- `__imp__` prefix (specific to gcc?)
- [Oracle command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1005123)

and possibly even more. [imp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imp) is short, but apparently not short enough to be unambiguous. As a result, it does not add any meaningful information to the post.

Should this tag be burninated?

Comment: You've also skipped over the fact that it is a legitimate command when using Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1005123 Possibly a better option is to clean up incorrect usages instead of burnination.